# make treating name of .out file as a prerequisite

Tags: makefile

Consider the following Makefile:

```
default: a.out
a:
    echo "hello"
```

The output I get when I run `make` is:

```
echo "hello"
hello
cp a a.out
cp: cannot stat 'a': No such file or directory
make: *** [<builtin>: a.out] Error 1
```

Can someone explain this? It seems to only happen with the `.out` file extension.

Comment: What you show does not correspond to any form of make I know. Why would make try to copy `a` to `a.out`? Please show a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Also provide the exact command you type (just `make` or `make <something>`?)

Comment: @RenaudPacalet My bad, I meant to say this is the output of the `make` command. I have updated my question. However, this is indeed a very minimal, complete, and verifiable example. I tested it in Linux and macOS.

Comment: Sorry, it was so bizarre that I did not even try. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make contains a number of built-in rules that allow it to perform common actions even if no makefile exists, or no rule for building a target exists in the makefile.

One of those rules is this (you can run `make -p -f/dev/null` to see a complete list):

```
%.out: %
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        @rm -f $@
         cp $< $@
```

Since your `default` target depends on `a.out` but no rule to build `a.out` exists in your makefile, make will look through the built-in rules to find one and discovers this one.  Then it needs to build `a` because `%.out` depends on `%`, and it finds a rule for that, so it runs the rules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This wasn't part of my original question, but if I have an a.out file in my local directory, but no rule for building it, make will rebuild it with the target you mentioned. Is there a way to just use the a.out file that is already present?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but you can simply remove the built-in rule, by adding the line `%.out : %` to your makefile (no recipe).  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html

Comment: Gosh! I should have tested myself instead of refusing to believe it. Thanks for the explanation, I learnt one more thing from you @MadScientist.